# VIM search for pattern into quickfix

Tags: vim

Basically I need to create a quickfix buffer listing all lines that match a regex.  What is the best way?

The global command may not be the best, but I think it should be usable.  The output of the global command is perfect, but I need it to *hyperlink* the matching lines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [caddexpr](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:caddexpr):-

```
g/<pattern>/caddexpr expand("%") . ":" . line(".") . ":" . getline(".")
```

Answer (score 32):

You can also not use the global command and stick with what is built-in.
Use the vimgrep command as below:

```
:vimgrep /pattern/ %
```

And then `:copen` or `:cwindow`

Comment: Personally, I think this is a better answer because it does the exact same thing as the accepted answer, but in a simpler, more compact fashion.

Comment: simple and effective!

Comment: :vimgrep, however, doesn't let you search through only a range of lines in the current file, which is sometimes desirable.