# How to search a pattern in between a string and show it in quick fix?

Tags: vim, vimgrep, vim-quickfix

In my log file some times there will be many errors. I will filter the errors between the lines and will see the files which are executed in between.

So in short I will search a pattern between ranges.

```
1000,2000g/.yaml:/#
```

now this result is display in screen. But I want it to be in quickfix so that I can select different lines till I complete. How to push this result into quickfix window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VIM search for pattern into quickfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330532/vim-search-for-pattern-into-quickfix)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the :cadde command together with your `g` command. There is a nice example in the help doc to show how it works:

```
:g/mypattern/caddexpr expand("%") . ":" . line(".") .  ":" . getline(".")
```

In your case, you just need to add the range and change the pattern. please check the doc for details:

```
:h cadde
```

After you put things into quickfix list, I've written a little plugin several years ago to allow you to do further filtering (multiple levels and undo-able) in the quickfix:

https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep